# Probot : Octokit baseUrl overriding

Tags: octokit, probot

Am trying to create a new GitHub(probot) application by going through documentation as mentioned here https://probot.github.io/docs/development/ .

I can get the events from the repository come across but have issues performing any operations with the Github Api client in the context(https://probot.github.io/api/latest/Context.html). From the console i see the default @octokit client is pointing to http://api.github.com instead of the enterprise URL in my case. Is there anything extra that needs to be done to change this URL.

I feel hesitant to create a new client with the correct URL in the robot.on method as we should use the authenticated client i.e available on the context. Am i missing anything here?

`22:01:15.370Z DEBUG github: GitHub request: GET /app/installations - 404 Not Found
  params: {
    "per_page": 100,
    "baseUrl": "https://api.github.com",
    "request": {
      "timeout": 0
    }
  }
22:01:15.371Z ERROR probot: {"message":"Integration not found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a bit more of documentation (https://probot.github.io/docs/github-api/#github-enterprise) - this could be achieved by setting the property GHE_HOST

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using an enterprise GitHub account and was able to resolve it by setting GHE_HOST. See below link for more details:

[GitHub ERROR probot: Integration not found, documentation_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844416/github-error-probot-integration-not-found-documentation-url)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the below property in the `.env` file of my probot resolved the issue.

`GHE_HOST=<<my GitHub enterprise url>>`