# GitHub ERROR probot: Integration not found, documentation_url

Tags: github, integration, documentation, probot

I had issues with authentication when working with GitHub's Probot app. When I ran the app using npm start, I would get

`github: Github request: GET /app/installations - 404 Not Found`

and

`ERROR probot: {"message":"Integration not found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

I later found that the reason I was getting this issue was because I was working from a GitHub Enterprise account and needed to add an extra variable to my .env file:

`GHE_HOST=github.your_company.com`

After restarting my app, I no longer had those issues.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I had previously not known how to solve this issue by using the GHE_HOST variable, but I was able to find the answer and fix it myself. Since it took me so long to find the solution, a colleague suggested I open up a Q&A here so as to help others who may come across the same issue. No further questions at this point!

Comment: It might be worth adding the solution as a separate answer anyway. I came here via Google, skim read your issue and was disappointed to see there were no answers, so I almost closed the tab. ;) Anyway, thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: @hmcollins3 is it possible to deploy without GHE_HOST ? Please advise. I am going through similiar problem.        msg: request to https://github.com/api/v3/app/installations?per_page=100 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ipaddress:443`  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Just want to add more information about the issue. `Integration` refers to your app. Double-check whether your app id is correct. Decode your JWT token and check if the `iss` matches your app id. And lastly, check your request, are you sending requests to the correct Github tenant (API url).